# What is the best way to normalize negative/non numerical data for tanh activation function neural networks

Tags: c++, machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, backpropagation

I'm using feed forward, gradient descent, backpropagation neural networks
where hidden/output neurons are using tanh activation function and input neurons are linear.

What is the best way, in your opinion, for normalizing numerical data if:

1. Maximum number is known and for example maximum positive number would be 1000 and maximum negative -1000.
2. Maximum number is unknown.

And if I should keep the maximum numbers same for all inputs or would it be okay
if network's inputs have different normalizing way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If `max` and `min` are known, the easiest normalization is :

```
normalized = (val - min) / (max - min)
```

If `max` is unknown, you can normalize based on the data you *do* have, with the knowledge that `tanh` has good characteristics for values that exceed a magnitude of 1.

You *should* normalize different inputs based on the range of values of those inputs and you *may* use different normalization procedures for different inputs.